# 'ipset add' from python script

Tags: python-3.x, ip, firewall, iptables

I have existing ipset `mylist`, which I created with this command:

```
ipset create mylist hash:net
```

Now, I would like to be able, from my python script, to add IPs to this list. This is the command I would use to do it manually from the commandline:

```
ipset add mylist 45.254.246.0/24
```

how can I do the same from python script?

I found the [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_03.html) module has `IPSet` support, but this seems to be just internal structure, not a module to interact with my `iptables`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path to `ipset` is `/usr/sbin/ipset`:

```
import os
os.system('/usr/sbin/ipset add mylist 45.254.246.0/24')
```